# Convert in java one json to another with different field

Tags: java, json, deserialization

For example I have next JSON:

```
{"name":"Joe"}
```

which is represented as Name.java entity:

```
public class Name
{
   @JsonProperty("name")
   public String name;
}
```

And I want to convert this json to another during unmarshalling of the rest response. The one I want convert to is looked like this:

```
public class Surname 
{
   @JsonProperty("surname");
   public String surname;
}
```

I don't want to use @JsonDeserializer on the whole class, in fact @JsonDeserializer on method will not work since the properties have different names, so how am I gonna convert first entity to the second one, using some @JsonCreator or what? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Name name = mapper....// unmarshalling and object mapping

JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(name);

// copy the value of name and remove the key, add a new key with same value

String n = node.get("name");
node.remove("name");
node.put("surname", n);
```

Edit:

With annotation you can try

```
public class name {
String name;
   @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("surname")
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
      this.name = surname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I can, but your example - is using @JsonDeserialize on class, am I right? That not what im looking for, thanks anyway!

Comment: where is it using JsonDeserialize?

Comment: After the REST response, you must be unmarshalling it using objectMapper right? Just ignore that part, that i have commented on also.

Comment: But I want my JSON object to be constructed without any extra code, just using annotations, for example I want to say mapper that you have to put this value into this variable by setting up some annotation like @JsonProperty